# Qt Signal mapper and sending QLabel by reference and OpenCv 2

Tags: c++, qt, pass-by-reference

i'm trying to write a code that takes a Qlabel by reference and view images on it using a timer signal, but i can't use the signal mapper properly

```
void ImgClass::changeWindowLabel(QLabel *windowLabel){
    CapObjLabel.open(0);
    CapObjLabel.read(orignFrame);
    cv::flip(orignFrame, orignFrame,1);

    QImage qimgOriginal((uchar*)orignFrame.data, orignFrame.cols, orignFrame.rows, orignFrame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    windowLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimgOriginal));

}


void ImgClass::waitForUser(QLabel *windowLabel){
    tmrWindowTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(tmrWindowTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),windowLblSignal, SLOT(map(QLabel*)));

    windowLblSignal->setMapping(windowLabel);

    connect(windowLblSignal, SIGNAL(mapped(QLabel*)), this, SLOT(changeWindowLabel(QLabel*)));
    tmrWindowTimer->start(30);
}
```

and here is the .h

```
public:
QSignalMapper* windowLblSignal;
cv::VideoCapture CapObjLabel;
cv::Mat orignFrame;
QImage qimgOriginal;
QTimer* tmrWindowTimer;

public:
    ImgClass();
    void waitForUser(QLabel *windowLabel);


public slots:

    void changeWindowLabel(QLabel* windowLabel);
```

i've tried to insert QObject or QWidget but it didn't work also
sorry, it is my frist question here, so i'm not sure that i'm doing it the right way.
thanks for help and reading my question

Edit:
how can i use a QLabel Object by reference to be edit when a Signal arrives from a timer or from a click event ?!

Edit 03/05/2014

after thuga response i made the following changes

```
void ImgClass::changeWindowLabel(QWidget *InputWidget){
    QLabel * windowLabel = qobject_cast<QLabel *>(InputWidget);
    CapObjLabel.open(0);
    CapObjLabel.read(orignFrame);
    cv::flip(orignFrame, orignFrame,1);

    QImage qimgOriginal((uchar*)orignFrame.data, orignFrame.cols, orignFrame.rows, orignFrame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    windowLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimgOriginal));

}


void ImgClass::waitForUser(QWidget *windowLabel){
    tmrWindowTimer = new QTimer(this);
    windowLblSignal = new QSignalMapper(windowLabel);
    connect(tmrWindowTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),windowLblSignal, SLOT(map()));

    windowLblSignal->setMapping(windowLabel, windowLabel);

    connect(windowLblSignal, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget*)), this, SLOT(changeWindowLabel(QWidget*)));
    tmrWindowTimer->start(30);
}
```

this is my call in the ui class

```
ImgClass mImgClass;
mImgClass.waitForUser(ui->lblNewValues);
```

and totally nothing happen !!!!

Comment: There is no signal mapped(QLabel*) in QSignalMapper. Moreover the method setMapping() with only senderparameter given, will remove all mappings.

Comment: how can i use a QLabel Object by reference to be edit when a Signal arrives from a timer or from a click event ?!

Comment: Use [`QSignalMapper::setMapping(QObject *sender, QWidget *widget)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html#setMapping-3) and [`QSignalMapper::mapped(QWidget *widget)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html#mapped-3) signal, then cast it to `QLabel` by using [`qobject_cast`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but would you give an example ?!

Comment: Would anybody give an example, cause even after the edit it doesn't work with me.

Comment: @Ramzy Check what your `connect` statements return. Check if your slot is executed.

Comment: the slot is not Executed, i made qDebug() but it didn't work

Comment: if anybody would check this link
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/42143/
that's me asking

Comment: `windowLblSignal->setMapping(windowLabel, windowLabel);` is wrong. *Adds a mapping so that when map() is signalled from the sender, the signal mapped(widget) is emitted.*. The sender should be your timer object.